# Symfony DomCrawler Absolute urls of scripts and stylesheets

Tags: php, symfony

Is there any way to get absolute urls of scripts and stylesheets?
For links it can be done in a simple way:

```
$crawler = new Crawler($html, $url);
$crawler->filter('a')->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) {
     $href = $node->link()->getUri();
});
```

But it doesn't work for js and css.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```php
$crawler = new Crawler($html, $url);
$crawler->filter('link')->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) {
     $href = $node->attr('href');
});
```

**UPDATE2**

```
    $html = <<<'HTML'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
       <link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/png" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/v5/all.js?v=4"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <img src="/images/v5/logos/header-logo.svg" alt="Symfony" class="img-responsive" />
       <p class="message">Hello World!</p>
       <p>Hello Crawler!</p>
    </body>
</html>
    HTML;

    $crawler = new Crawler($html);

    $websiteName = 'http://myCoolWebsite.com';

    var_dump($websiteName . $crawler->filter('link')->first()->attr('href'));
    var_dump($websiteName . $crawler->filter('img')->first()->attr('src'));
    var_dump($websiteName . $crawler->filter('script')->first()->attr('src'));
```

OUTPUT:

```
string(45) "http://myCoolWebsite.com/apple-touch-icon.png"
string(56) "http://myCoolWebsite.com//images/v5/logos/header-logo.svg"
string(41) "http://myCoolWebsite.com/js/v5/all.js?v=4"
```

Comment: You meant $crawler->filter('link')? Because there is no 'stylesheet' tag. If so - yes, I've tried this. And for 'script', 'link' and 'img' it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, but it still doesn't work. I've said that I need an absolute url but attr() give a relative one.

Comment: You have the absolute path, you should concatenate it with the your website name or ip address: `$href = 'http://my_cool_website.com' . $node->link()->getUri();`

Comment: Ok, it works for <link>. But still doesn't for <script> and <img>.
'Unable to navigate from a "img"/"script" tag.'